# Is there a list of middleware included with Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

[The docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) talk about how to use various middleware (app.use) but I can't find a list of available middleware on the ExpressJS site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express uses the Connect framework for middleware.  You can find a list on the [senchalabs connect homepage](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/).